Another question about setting and reading Access checkboxes with VBA
Handicapping ReportI'm hoping I can find someone with a good deal of patience and can reply at a less than expert level to me.  I've been working with Access/Excel/VBA for many years, and used to be the "go-to" guy in the workplace, but am now in my 70's and my thinking abilities are declining rapidly.  This relatively simple task (I believe) has me stumped.
I've looked all over for how to set an unbound checkbox to False (NOTE: I don't really understand bound/unbound well because it was never a need to understand, but I believe it refers to being tied to a query or form or something similar versus unbound which means "standalone".  If not, please let me know).
There are plenty of queries and procedures that initially populate this report, all which work flawlessly and should be of no concern with regards to this question.  The last step of the sub that generates the report opens the report.
Within the Subroutine, I want to add some code to set the value (to FALSE) of checkboxes that I want to add.  The code would be placed within the sub, immediately after the report is opened.
The body of the report is a listing of horses in a race along with all the pertinent info I've been collecting to improve my handicapping skills.  What I would like to do is to now add checkboxes so that I can "hide" those horses (the entire row of data for a given horse; I don't want to delete the row, just hide/filter etc.) who have scratched or which I'm not interested in seeing.  Hiding them would clean up the report to make reviewing the remaining possibilities much clearer.
But I'm not sure how to properly set up the checkboxes.  Bear in mind that if there's a better way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.  I'm not married to the concept of using checkboxes.  If it's not too complex, I can try different approaches (I don't want to mess up what's already working though).
Specifically, I want to set the checkboxes to False when the report opens.  As it is now, they open in a null state (gray in the middle).  This doesn't seem right since they're set for "Triple = No", so that's problem 1.
Once I know how to set them, I then envision clicking a "requery" button (or do it programmatically) and READ the state of each checkbox to determine which horses to hide.  I'll address the actual procedure for doing that after I get through this point.
I've searched high and low online and there's a lot of discussion of this topic as it pertains to Excel, but I believe this is a different animal.
Attached is a screenshot of a part of the report, hopefully adding clarity to my explanation above.  I've also attached a screenshot of the code I've tried using.  I have this placed as the last step in the long subroutine that leads up to the creation and display of the report.
Here are different approaches I've tried:
Check190.Value = False (Check190 is one of the 20 checkboxes)
Me.Check190.Value = False
rpt_raceScoreCardv2.Check190 = False

If I'm not being clear, PLEASE let me know.
And thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide.

BTW, there is no screenshot of code. Code should be provided as formatted text, not images.

Yes BOUND means connected to data (table/query and fields). I tested code in report Load event to set Value of checkbox and it works. Could just have expression in ControlSource: =0, no VBA needed.

When you want to access a checkbox on your report from VBA code outside the report, you must reference it via the report object.
Here is an example from the Immediate window.  The report, Report3, contains an unbound checkbox named Check0 ...
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report3", acViewReport

? Reports!Report3!Check0.Value
Null

Reports!Report3!Check0.Value = False
? Reports!Report3!Check0.Value
False

Reports!Report3!Check0.Value = True
? Reports!Report3!Check0.Value
True


I feel you should rethink your approach. You should be checking boxes on your form (not your report). Do you have a Main Form where you enter parameters to populate a Subform that provides a list of candidate horses?? If so, this is where you should include your checkboxes so you can make your selection and print the report based off that. The Report should be based on the same Query as you Subform.

I'm not using any forms at all.  All the information fed to the database tables are via automation.  My master table is a composite of four linked Excel files--plus internal calculations--which contain various aspects of the data I'm working with; one has horse past performances, one has jockey and trainer records, one has the current days races, etc.
Queries in a master Subroutine do all the work; I don't need to enter any data manually.  Thus, my main report is the only representation of the data within.

Just an update to my previous comment.  After giving n00dnutt's suggestion some further thought, I tried creating a form in place of the on-record checkboxes I had finally figured out.  That actually worked better as I did it as a pop-up so now I can have both my Report and the form visible simultaneously and it's MUCH more effective.  So thanks, n00dnutt.

Hi Richard, you're most welcomed. If you feel your question is answered, can you mark it as answered and vote on it please.
